# Landscape Server / multiple errors on cron job

Tags: server, cron, proxy, landscape

Sebastian here, looking for some answers on Landscape server.

I set up an Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS and installed Landscape Server 19.10. For a while, the system was running fine but since a few days it keeps running into connection errors etc. when running Landscape's cron jobs.

Following scripts won't work properly and keep sending me eMails:
/opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/meta_releases.sh
/opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/report_anonymous_metrics.sh
/opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/update_security_db.sh

I'm trying to solve these problems myself but can't find some solution... It's kinda annoying ;-)

Here are the error reports:

- meta_releases.sh

```
<11>Jun 10 00:30:05 meta-releases: Failed to fetch http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release: 'Error 35: gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.'
```

- report-anonymous-metrics

```
<11>Jun 10 00:55:01 report-anonymous-metrics: Error running /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/report_anonymous_metrics.sh: 0 <11>Jun 10 00:55:09 report-anonymous-metrics: Check out the syslog output for script report-anonymous-metrics.
```

- update_security_db.sh

```
<11>Jun 10 06:42:33 update-security-db: Traceback (most recent call last):
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:   File "./process-usns", line 7, in <module>
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:     canonical.landscape.scripts.usn.run()
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 76, in __call__
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:     self.setup()
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 121, in setup
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:     self._add_cleanup_callback(self.run_amqp_client_in_thread(config))
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/setup.py", line 336, in run_amqp_client_in_thread
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:     blockingCallFromThread(reactor, lambda: started)
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/threads.py", line 122, in blockingCallFromThread
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:     result.raiseException()
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db:   File "<string>", line 2, in raiseException
<11>Jun 10 06:42:45 update-security-db: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
Error running /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/update_security_db.sh: 0 Check out the syslog output for script update_security_db.sh.
```

As my Server is running behind a proxy, I double checked (triple checked) my configuration files and everything *seems* to be fine. Running curl manually to download meta-releases works fine, too.

I'd be happy for any insights here.

**Update 15.06.2020:**

Thanks for your comments!

I read about cron and proxy earlier and set my variables accordingly.

Here's my /etc/environment:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
export http_proxy=http://{proxy-fqdn-here}:3128
export https_proxy=http://{proxy-fqdn-here}:3128
export ftp_proxy=http://{proxy-fqdn-here}:21
export no_proxy=localhost,{hostname-here},{hostname-fqdn-here}
#export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
#export HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy
#export FTP_PROXY=$ftp_proxy
#export NO_PROXY=$no_proxy
```

Here's the /etc/crontab, same config:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
http_proxy=http://{proxy-fqdn-here}:3128
https_proxy=http://{proxy-fqdn-here}:3128
ftp_proxy=http://{proxy-fqdn-here}:21
no_proxy=localhost,{hostname-here},{hostname-fqdn-here}
#HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
#HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy
#FTP_PROXY=$ftp_proxy
#NO_PROXY=$no_proxy

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

I even entered my proxy config in /etc/profile and /etc/security/pam_env.conf but it didn't help me here.

Best regards from Solingen, Germany

Sebastian

Comment: I am not familiar with landscape but it’s not unusual for cron jobs to have problems with permissions and keys. If you run a job as your user it will use a different set of keys to the root user under cron. Probably not the answer but any input may give a different perspective that could lead to a solution. Good luck!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is cron jobs may not share the same environment as your users. Landscape scripts source /etc/environment, which is a common place for globally defining http_proxy/https_proxy variables. If your proxy configuration is defined elsewhere (in your bashrc), this probably won't work. That could explain why you get different results when running scripts manually.